# OPENXML vs OPENROWSET and xml data type

Tags: sql-server, xml

Why would you ever use OPENXML instead of OPENROWSET (BULK 'file', SINGLE_BLOB) and cast to the xml data type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think those are quite different things you're comparing here:

- **OPENROWSET** just simply imports a file on disk as a single blob - this works great if you do need that file content as a single big chunk of information - if you want to store the entire file contents as a single XML field
- **OPENXML** is very different - it will open and interpret the XML file and will turn it into a rowset - it will give you rows and columns of data, based off that source XML file, and you can then store that information in a table - in rows and columns. You're not getting the XML as a single big chunk, but it's been "shredded" into rows and columns for you

So it really depends on what your needs are - if you need the XML as a big chunk and store it that was - use **OPENROWSET**.

If you need the data represented in the XML as columns and rows, use **OPENXML** (or alternatively: use the OPENROWSET first to import the XML as a whole, and then use the XQuery functions in SQL Server 2005 and up to shred it once you've loaded it)

Comment: Your last sentence states why I view these as two ways of doing the same thing: loading and querying xml. Assuming you want to query it--not just store it--why would you pick one over the other?

Comment: @Daniel: personally, I find the bulk-load with OPENROWSET and then use XQuery to query (or optionally shred) the XML the easier path

Comment: The xml data type (combined with OPENROWSET BULK) appears to supercede, and obsolete, OPENXML.

Comment: Hi, it's 10 years later, but I'm creating an XML course, and want to get this right.  Would OPENROWSET be used when data is on disk, and OPENXML used when data is already in memory?

Comment: OPENROWSET just loads the contents of the file - whatever that is - into a SQL Server variable - it's totally unrelated to XML or anything else - it just loads data into variables. OPENXML is an older, legacy way of opening an XML file and providing a relational row/columns dataset - I'd strongly advise to use OPENROWSET to load the file, and then the native XQuery support to parse the XML in the SQL variable

Comment: But OPENROWSET returns an XML Column, which allows one to do .query and .value statements, and can be processed without OPENXML, right?  I don't believe you need to do sp_xml_preparedocument with OPENROWSET.

Comment: OPENROWSET just returns the contents of the file you're loading - and if that file happens to contain XML, then yes, the SQL Server variable can be of type `XML` and queried with XQuery **without** having to go through `sp_xml_preparedocument` and all those legacy, memory-leaking methods

Comment: Ah, I see now that OPENROWSET works with .csv files too (any I guess any OLEDB source) - I didn't know that before.